# Foreach instead of options binding... how can I replicate "optionsCaption" functionality?

Tags: knockout.js

I have been working with KnockoutJS this week and have quite a specific problem that I am hoping someone else has run into and solved before me...

Essentially I am binding up a select box but needed to be able to have control over the actual options tags themselves (disable for example) so that meant that I was unable to use the "options" binding which of course does not give you fine grained control over the options tags... here is what I came up with (it works!)

```
<select data-bind="foreach: $root.availableLabels, value: Label, enable: !IsConfirmed(), optionsCaption: 'Please select...'">
    <option data-bind="text: Value, value: $data, css: { 'paired-label': IsPaired }, disable: IsPaired"></option>
</select>
```

My issue is with the "optionsCaption", as I am using a foreach method to generate the inner options this does not automatically work like it would if I was able to use the simpler "Options" binding found on the knockout page... so if the objects I am iterating have a null "Label" value it simply displays the first one in the list as opposed to "Please Select..." which is what I would ideally like.

Does anyone know a way around this? I have not posted my view model code as I am not sure it's relevant actually but if needed of course just ask!

In short the problem is that I need to use foreach so that I can set css / attr bindings on the options however still need a "unselected" option.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard options binding provides a method to post-process the binding. For that you'll want to use `optionsAfterRender`.

You can find a complete example, specifically for disabling options within the `<select>` on the [knockout.js options documentation page at the very bottom](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

Quoted from that page:

> If you need to run some further custom logic on the generated option elements, you can use the optionsAfterRender callback. The callback function is invoked each time an option element is inserted into the list, with the following parameters:
>
> - The inserted option element
> - The data item against which it is bound, or undefined for the caption element

```
<select size=3 data-bind="
    options: myItems,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    optionsAfterRender: setOptionDisable">
</select>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = {
        myItems: [
            { name: 'Item 1', id: 1, disable: ko.observable(false)},
            { name: 'Item 3', id: 3, disable: ko.observable(true)},
            { name: 'Item 4', id: 4, disable: ko.observable(false)}
        ],
        setOptionDisable: function(option, item) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {disable: item.disable}, item);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Ultimately, this means that you have to **modify your bound collection** to include observable properties, which can then be referenced in the post-processing function. If I understand the documentation correctly, **updating the observables** should also re-run your post-processor.

EDITS : You can also use this

```
self.setOptionDisable= function(option, item) {
    option.disabled = item.disable()
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help! Works a treat!

Comment: @raheel_shan are you sure the part that you edited in works? Because item.disable is actually an observable, thus you should need `item.disable()` or better `ko.unwrap(item.disable)`.

Comment: Can confirm that... needed to unwrap the observable... but otherwise... thanks!

Comment: Well i am sure. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303689/knockout-multiselect-selectedoptions-contains-values-instead-of-objects/24303773#24303773) in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use containerless `foreach`loop to generate the options after a fixed *"Please select..."* option:

```
<select data-bind="value: Label, enable: !IsConfirmed()">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.availableLabels -->
    <option data-bind="text: Value, 
                       value: $data, 
                       css: { 'paired-label': IsPaired },
                       disable: IsPaired"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HyYm8/3/)

Comment: Thanks very much for this.. it looks simple! The unfortunate thing about this option is that IE8 will remove comments from within the select which means that the foreach will not work if done using the comment syntax! Alas I tried and failed with this! (I need to provide IE8 support)

Comment: I see, IE8... There is a discussion about this problem here:[knockout.js: using a containerless foreach on a select fails in Internet Explorer 8]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723451/knockout-js-using-a-containerless-foreach-on-a-select-fails-in-internet-explo) that might help you or someone else.